# Sitecore Workflow Issue

Tags: sitecore, workflow, sitecore7

I have a page item with A template and there are some components, such as HTML container, RSS, SlideShow and etc under this page item. Also, these all components have its own template (B, C, D templates).

I have a workflow (draft, approval, publish states) and assigned this workflow to each template's standard values (A, B, C, D templates).

However, most content editors access page editor and update some contents in the components. Then, they just submit the page item because they don't know what components are using in this page item (they doesn't need to consider too).

Once the page item submitted, the page item goes to approval state. **HOWEVER**, all components under this page item are still in draft state.

Does it make a sense???

All child items have to be the same approval state as its parent item (page item).

Comment: This behavior is by design. You end up in this situation because you're heading down the wrong path with your information architecture. That said, you will need to cook up some custom workflow code to complete this scenario.

Comment: @MarkCassidy Thanks for the replying. So, do you mean the tree architecture is wrong when I first create this structure? In your case, where do you make all those components reside?

Comment: Well. Sitecore sees your page item as "the page", where all your content for the page sits. That is about as far as many of the built in tools will take you. Now in recent years it has become commonplace to have less fields on the page item itself (almost none) and then use components and datasources to put together your final output. If that's what you are doing, you are not on the wrong track. I worried that because you have them as child items, you were building your own rendering solution, e.g. looping through .Children and deciding what to render.